# Application of this kind of recursion

Tags: recursion

I cant figure out where do we use this structure for recursion in a problem and what is this called

```
int func001(int x){

    if(x>=1) func003(x-1);

}
int func003(int y){

    if(y>=2) func001(y-1);

}
```

Comment: Where did you see this code? What kind of problem is it solving in its original source? As it is, this code doesn't really do much. It just keeps calling these two functions back and forth with smaller and smaller values of `x`/`y` until it gets to 1 or 0, depending on the original value and which is called first.

Comment: It is called [mutual recursion](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Mutual_recursion).

Comment: And neither function actually returns anything for either the base case or the recursive case, so as is, they're pretty much useless...

Comment: this code does not represents an algorithm it just means to say , a function A calls another function B which calls A and so on... where do we use such a kind of recursion , i mean which problems\algorithms .

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This kind of recursion is called [mutual recursion](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Mutual_recursion).  Your code example is not well defined, so it is not possible to tell what is here intended.

Nevertheless, the most common use of mutual recursive functions is to encode a finite state automaton: each state is represented by a function and transitions are represented by calls to other functions.  This is for instance the case in lexical analysers generated by `lex` and similar programs, but also often the case in hand-written lexical analysers.